# How to write Ω or any other greek alphabet letter in textual file?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is: Code::Blocks 20.03 ( compiler: mingw 9.2.0 )

The example code is:

```
program greek_letters

implicit none

write(*,*) "resistance is 100 Ω"

end program
```

When I start the program, I get a message stating that there has been a change to the UTF 8 encoding because data lose prevention.

Is there any reason for not using greek letters for writing enginering results in .txt files?

Comment: What exact message do you get?

Comment: @VladimirF It is a messeage from the IDE stating something along the line that one of the characters was not in the selected file encoding and the file is therefore saved as UTF-8.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: It is not a problem, just a message.

Comment: @VladimirF I got message which was mentioned by Tine198 so i just need explanation about it.

Comment: @HarryKastorp  I will stress it one more time, the message did NOT mean that the compiler would not  handle the symbols correctly. It was only a note from the text editor, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think having the source file in UTF-8 is a big problem. If the compiler does not support UTF-8 it will see multiple characters and output them but if the output file or output terminal does support UTF-8 they should be able to interpret the characters correctly. The only problem would happen if the compiler somehow tried to re-interpret the characters it does not understand in the character literal. I do not know if that happens for any compiler in the wild.

Be aware that an UTF-8 character will span over several default characters depending (ASCII bytes) on the actual value. The capital Greek omega is two bytes 0xCE 0xA9.

Both Intel Fortran and gfortran display the following program correctly in my Linux terminal. If any compiler did differently, I would question the quality of the implementation. It is just the matter of having the correct fonts in the terminal (and also in your web browser to be able to see it here).

```
print *, "Ω Ⱖ 世界"
end
```

The warning you got is really just a warning from your IDE that it had to introduce an UTF-8 character, nothing more. Note that the length of the string is 13 default gfortran characters. (I assumed you are not using some weird EBCDIC compiler on a mainframe).

Comment: All the calculations that I perform, for now, at the faculty concern electrical quantities and all those quantities, after the calculations, I write in text files in a correct way with the corresponding units for certain variables (in this case for impedance). For some, it is necessary to use Greek symbols.
I downloaded the student version of the latest intel compiler for Visual Studio 2019 community and did not receive such notice.

Comment: Having in mind the fact that I am a beginner in the fortran programming language and that mymentioned  IDE is free and contains the autocomplete code, I will continue to use it to fulfill my university obligations.

Comment: This doesn't neccessarily work on windows, it depends on what codepage the console is set. On my machine it doesn't ... to get it to work I have to execute chcp 65001 prior execution of the program.

Comment: @Tine198 I did assume it may be the case, Windows being Windows, and hence did write a disclaimer. No-one would expect an UTF-8 string to be properly displayed on a non-unicode terminal.

Comment: @HarryKastorp I do not understand what you are saying but it probably does not matter. The message was from an IDE. Even if Visual Studio does not issue such a message the "problem" is still there. You can also just safely use your old IDE. Just use what works better for you. Do not that the code in the answer you have accepted will probably not write the symbol correctly to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Not all compilers do support Unicode characters, so if you use Unicode characters your program may behave differently, when compiled with another compiler. 
I think neither ifort nor the IBM compiler supports ISO_10646  at the moment. 
Personally I would write "Ohm" instead.

That being said, this works with gfortran 8.1.0:

```
program test
implicit none
integer, parameter ::  ucs4  = selected_char_kind ('ISO_10646')
character(kind=ucs4):: OhmSymbol = char(int(z'03A9'),kind=ucs4)

open(14,file='test.txt',status='unknown', encoding='UTF-8')
write(14,*) "14", OhmSymbol    
close(14)

end program test
```

Comment: I think this is an unnecessary complication in most cases leading to strings that are very difficult to read if they contain longer parts written in non-ASCII scripts (Russian, Bulgarian, Greek, Chinese, Korean...) or even in laguages with diacritics (Czech, Polish, Hungarian). Writing everything in `char(,kind=ucs4)` appears even practically impossible to me.

Comment: Also, the standard output will typically have the `UNKNOWN` encoding so this will not write the correct output for displaying in the terminal.